# Use child's last values for new child feature

Tags: qgis, qgis-expression, attribute-form

I have a layer "trees" and a child layer "observations". When I create a new child, I do not want to fill in all the data (e.g. `vitality`) again. Each observation has a date - what should be the default expression for an attribute form so it takes the "vitality" status (int from 1-5) as default value for the new observation?

I tried so far:

`attribute(get_feature('observations', 'Date', to_date(maximum("date"))), 'vitality')`
-> this fills the vitality of the most recent observation as default. I need it to be the most recent per tree ID. I'm a bit lost how to implement that filter.

For better representation I created some sample data of my observation-table. Note that one tree (as defined in`tree_id`) can have multiple consecutive observations over time. The idea is that when creating a new observation the field worker has not to fill in all the (unchanged) attributes again (usually not much is changed, maybe a slight improvement or degrading in `vitality` or a newly discovered damage).

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use aggregate fuction [`array_agg()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-agg) to collect all vitality-values, grouped by tree_id, ordered by date. Exclude the current feature (the one you want to update) with optional filter condition. Use this expression:

```
array_last( 
    array_agg (
        vitality, 
        group_by:=tree_id, 
        order_by:=date, 
        filter:=$id<>id
    )
)
```

[image]

Comment: this works perfectly! One question: why use the filter? (I do not have an ID field, only fid (the layer is in a geopackage) - the fid is calculated after saving the feature so the filter is not possible to implement i think. But even without the filter option, it does what it should do!

Comment: I'm not sure at what step you use the expression. In my case, I have to include the filter - otherwise, the current feature (the one you want to create the vitality value, based on the most recent value from same tree_id) is included in the array and since the field is empty, a `NULL` value is included, so the output will be `NULL` as well. If for you it works without the filter, even better!

Answer (score 1):

If your tree ID is alphanumerically sortable and always increasing, you can simply switch the date field to the tree ID field:

`attribute(get_feature('observations', 'tree_id', maximum("tree_id")), 'vitality')`

Comment: unfortunately the tree_id is not always increasing, as in tree_observations there are many observations connected to the same tree (via the field tree_id) -